# Problemas ao usar camera, gerar, editar e salvar imagem

Tags: java, android

Tô tentando criar um app, e parte dele é usar a camera do celular pra tirar uma foto, que automaticamente será diminuída e salva em pastas separadas por ano / mes/ imgHora.jpg.

Para versões antigas o código funcionou, mas pra versões mais recentes tá dando erro. Já vi diversas perguntas similares em inglês e português, porém não consegui resolver, se alguém puder me dar um help agradeço. Já tentei usar Provider, mas só piorei tudo.
O erro principal é este:

> android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/CamMur/2018/October/28_182120.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

Referente à:

```
mIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(caminho)));
```

Outra coisa, quero que ao clicar de novo no botão, ele gere uma nova imagem.
Se alguém tiver uma solução melhor que esta minha é bem vinda. Sem ele, a primeira vez que entro no programa e clico no botão ele gera uma imagem e salva, mas se eu clicar denovo no botão ele sobrepoem a foto anterior.

```
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
```

Código completo:

```
package com.example.admin.camera;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int PROCESSO_TIRAR_FOTO = 10;

    private Context context;

    private ImageView iv_foto;
    private Button btn_tf;

    private int largura;
    private int altura;

    private String caminho;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.telainicial);

        iniciarVariaveis(savedInstanceState);
        iniciarAcoes();

    }

    @Override
    //se a tela morrer, faz cast e recria a tela;
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        outState.putInt("largura", largura);
        outState.putInt("altura", altura);
        outState.putString("caminho", caminho);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void iniciarVariaveis(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //bundle variavel de cache
        context = getBaseContext();
        //
        iv_foto = findViewById(R.id.iv_foto);
        btn_tf = findViewById(R.id.btn_tf);

        //Permissão para acessar camera
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 0);
        }

        //
        //Analisa savedInstance para recuperar os valores e inicializar as variaveis
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            altura = savedInstanceState.getInt("altura");
            largura = savedInstanceState.getInt("largura");
            //
            caminho = savedInstanceState.getString("caminho");


        } else {
            File path;
            File dir;

            String timeYear;
            String timeMoth;
            String timeDayHour;
            String timeAll;

            timeYear = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            timeMoth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            timeDayHour ="/" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + ".jpg";
            timeAll = "CamMur/" +timeYear + "/" + timeMoth ;


            //Cria pasta com nome CamMUR e um arquivo temporário foto.jpg
            path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                        dir = new File(path, timeAll);


            if (!dir.exists()) {
                if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d("LabCamera", "Pasta não criada");

                }
            }

            caminho = dir.getPath() + timeDayHour ;
        }
    }

    private void iniciarAcoes() {
        btn_tf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);

                largura = iv_foto.getWidth();
                altura = iv_foto.getHeight();
                //
                //chamar camera
                //não é de forma explicita, pois não sei a classe que chama a camera
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //saida da foto pro caminho criado;

                mIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(caminho)));
                //
                startActivityForResult(mIntent, PROCESSO_TIRAR_FOTO);


            }


        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PROCESSO_TIRAR_FOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    configurarImagem(resultCode);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Operação Cancelada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

        }


    private void configurarImagem(int resultCode) {
        int larguraFOTO;
        int alturaFOTO;

        //Não gera um bitmap. Ele inicializa a variavel options com as informações
        // vindas da imagem: altura e largura;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        //não consome a foto
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(caminho, options);

        larguraFOTO = options.outWidth;
        alturaFOTO = options.outHeight;

        //Divide a largura da foto pela largura do ImageView
        int escala = Math.min(larguraFOTO /largura, alturaFOTO/altura);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = escala;

        //GERA O BITMAP
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(caminho, options);

        iv_foto.setImageBitmap(bm);

    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.camera">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos direto no ponto, que está ocasionando o erro.

Está faltando a declaração do [File Provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider). Insira no `Manifest.xml`:

```
<application>
.
.
.
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>

</application>
```

E crie o arquivo `provider_paths` e diretório `xml` (caso não esteja criado). Com o seguinte código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Você precisará modificar a chamada da `intent` da Câmera:

```
mIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileUtil.getUri(getApplicationContext(), new File(caminho)));
```

Para a `Activity` não ficar gigante, crie uma nova classe contendo o código do `FileUtil`, com a finalidade de separar o tipo de chamada, pela versão do android no dispositivo:

```
public class FileUtil {
    public static Uri getUri(Context context, File file) {
        Uri uri;
        if (isAndroidMarshmallowOrSuperiorVersion()) {
            uri = getUriFrom(context, file);
        } else {
            uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        }
        return uri;
    }

    private static Uri getUriFrom(Context context, File file) {
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, getAuthority(), file);
    }

    @NonNull
    private static String getAuthority() {
        return BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider";
    }

    private static boolean isAndroidMarshmallowOrSuperiorVersion() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado. tava quebrando a cabeça pra utilizar FileProvider. Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Para parte de clicar no botão e gerar uma nova imagem sem sobrepor a anterior que foi tirada. Apenas removi:

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
```

E acrescentei o código que gera a imagem em:

```
 private void iniciarAcoes(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        btn_tf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Analisa savedInstance para recuperar os valores e inicializar as variaveis
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                altura = savedInstanceState.getInt("altura");
                largura = savedInstanceState.getInt("largura");
                //
                caminho = savedInstanceState.getString("caminho");


            } else {
                File path;
                File dir;
                ...
```